# Another functional inequality

Tags: inequalities, functional-equations

Is there some general solution to the functional inequality:

$$  f(xy) \leq y f(x) + x f(y)$$

Where $x,y\in[0,1]$?

I can find many particular solutions but I just wonder if there is a more general description of functions f satisfying such functional inequality. I have the following conditions

1) $f : [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$

2) $f$ is non-negative on $[0,1]$

3) $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1)$ is positive and finite, let say normalised to $1$

4) $f$ is one time continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: You might note that all nondecreasing nonnegative functions on $[0,1]$ satisfy the inequality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I am very sorry I did a really stupid mistake in specifying the inequality. Now it is the right one I am interested in.

Comment: Take a subadditive function $g$, then the funcion $f(x):=xg(\log x)$ satisfies your inequality. Conversely, if $f$ verifies your inequality, $g(x):=e^{-x}f(e^x)$ is subadditive.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity#Definitions

Answer (score 0):

Robert gave me an idea with his comment "...nondecreasing nonnegative functions....".
In fact if I divide my original inequality by the product x*y my inequality become:
f(xy) <= f(x) + f(y) and then a general answer to my question can be:

Take a non decreasing nonnegative function g(x). Then the function f(x) = x*g(x) satisfies the inequality f(x*y) <= x*f(y) + y*f(x)

Thanks for your help
Gianfranco